# Type string is not assignable to type number

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am new at angular and i have problem with this error:

> Type string is not assignable to type number

This is how my files look like:

**novo-fizicko-lice.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { FizickoLice } from '../klase/fizicko-lice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-novo-fizicko-lice',
  templateUrl: './novo-fizicko-lice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./novo-fizicko-lice.component.css']
})
export class NovoFizickoLiceComponent implements OnInit {

  prezime: string = "";
  ime: string = "";
  imeOca: string = "";
  jmb: string = "";
  mjestoStanovanja: string = "";
  napomena: string = "";
  datum: Date;
  obustavljenaIstraga: boolean;

  upisanoFizickoLice: FizickoLice;
  novoFizckoLiceForma = new FormControl();
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public adduser() {
    console.log("test clikc");

    this.datum = new Date;

    const novoFizickoLice: FizickoLice = {
      Ime: this.ime,
      Prezime: this.prezime,
      ImeOca: this.imeOca,
      JMB: this.jmb,
      MjestoStanovanja: this.mjestoStanovanja,
      Napomena: this.napomena,
      DatumUnosenjaLica: this.datum,
      ObustavljenaIstraga: this.obustavljenaIstraga
    };

    this.api.AddNewUser(novoFizickoLice).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.upisanoFizickoLice = data;

    });

  }

}
```

**fizicko-lice.ts**

```
export interface FizickoLice {
  Ime: string;
  Prezime: string;
  ImeOca: string;
  JMB: number; 
  MjestoStanovanja: string;
  DatumUnosenjaLica: Date | string;
  Napomena: string;
  ObustavljenaIstraga: boolean;
}
```

I'm getting error in this file novo-fizicko-lice. component.this on line

JMB: this.jmb,

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well, as your error message says, you're trying to assign a string to a number. You could try: "JMB: +this.jmb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to assing a String value in a Number type. Maybe you are using a number between quotation marks like this `'1'` or `"2"` and TS recognize it as String.

Comment: Thank you so much jmb: string = "";   just like you said, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error says it all:

`NovoFizickoLiceComponent::jmb` is declared as `string`, but `FizickoLice::JMB` is a `number`. And when you create a `new FizickoLice` in the `addUser` method you try to initialize the number `jmb` with the string `JMB` which is not allowed.

You should either change the type of `NovoFizickoLiceComponent::jmb` to `number`

```
jmb: number = 0;
```

or convert the string to a number before assigning by

```
JMB: +(this.jmb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from your variable `jmb`.
In your interface `FizickoLice` you're declaring JMB as a number.
In your component you're assigning it a string.

```
const novoFizickoLice: FizickoLice = {
  Ime: this.ime,
  Prezime: this.prezime,
  ImeOca: this.imeOca,
  JMB: this.jmb, <---- Here, this.jmb is a string.
  MjestoStanovanja: this.mjestoStanovanja,
  Napomena: this.napomena,
  DatumUnosenjaLica: this.datum,
  ObustavljenaIstraga: this.obustavljenaIstraga
};
```

Just change the type when you create the variable.
`jmb: number;`